# how to get file name and extension from directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a folder and I am trying to get all file names and file extension. How could I do this? 
I couldn't find any helpful example to do this, I am already tired  looking for it if anyone could help me with that it will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dir.glob("*")
# => ["test.rb", "a.txt", ..... ]
# or find all files recursively
Dir.glob("./**/*")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use php function `scandir('path')`